# Port Forwarding to allow access to my SFTP Server

Tags: port-forwarding, port

I have currently set up my SFTP Server using port 56.
In my router I have made a rule so that when traffic comes through on port 56 it's coming from one IP address being my public IP and being forwarded onto my server address.

I'm hoping Ive got the right idea here's what I've done.

Where it says internal IP I put my public address and then in source IP I put my server address, so when traffic is coming from one IP it's sent to my server to allow me to access it whenever I need too?

Only issue I'm having is when I setup this rule canyouseeme says the port is closed, is this because both my internal IP and external IP is different?

Answer (score 2):

You have it backwards, the source IP is any (or just leave it blank) to allow all traffic from any outside host, with the internal IP being the local IP address of your server, to send that outside traffic to that internal address. The source and destination ports would both be 56.

Comment: Right ok but if I don't put the same IP address when I port forward it doesn't open the port??

Comment: @DanPatto the same IP as what? Your firewall/router defines the source as an external device, the destination is an internal device. Source is any (meaning anywhere from outside of the router) and the translated destination (the place it forwards to) is always the internal IP address of your SSH server. The ports remain the same on both. That's all that's required in most cases, unless your router doesn't auto generate firewall rules, in which case you need to allow all incoming traffic on port 56 in your firewall settings.